# retrieve file from remote ftp to a webserver

Tags: java, ftp, webserver, ftp-client

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I just start the ftp and webserver thing so I get a little bit confused about it, particularly about the InputStream, fileInputStream and outputStream etc this kind of concepts. So I try to extend the program I write called web server and make it act as a FTP client that request txt file only. So  when request a text file (.txt) from within my web browser, the web server will not have a copy of this file. It will instantiate an FtpClient, retrieve the text file from your local FTP server and then send it back to your web browser as an HTTP response.
My code works fine for web server part, following is part of my code:

```
// Get a reference to the socket's input and output streams.
 InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
// Set up input stream filters.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

...

```
  // Extract the filename from the request line.
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(requestLine);
    // skip over the method, which should be "GET"
    tokens.nextToken();
    String fileName = tokens.nextToken();
    // Prepend a "." so that file request is within the current directory.
    fileName = "." + fileName;

    // Open the requested file.
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    boolean fileExists = true;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        fileExists = false;
    }

    // Construct the response message.
    String statusLine = null;
    String contentTypeLine = null;
    String entityBody = null;
    if (fileExists) {
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF;
        contentTypeLine = "Content-type: " + contentType(fileName) + CRLF;
    }
    // file doesn't exist
    else {
        // if the file requested is any type other than a text (.txt) file,
        // report // error to the web client
        if (!contentType(fileName).equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain")) {

            statusLine = "404 Not Found" + CRLF;
            contentTypeLine = "no content" + CRLF;
            entityBody = "<HTML>" + "<HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>" + "<BODY>Not Found</BODY></HTML>";
        } else {
            String server = "127.0.0.1";
            // else retrieve the text (.txt) file from your local FTP server
            statusLine = "200 OK" + CRLF;
            contentTypeLine = "Content-type: " + contentType(fileName) + CRLF;
            // create an instance of ftp client
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
            // connect to the ftp server
            ftp.connect(server);
            ftp.login(userName, password);
            // retrieve the file from the ftp server, remember you need to
            // // first upload this file to the ftp server under your user
            // ftp directory

            ftp.retrieveFile("/folder1/"+ fileName.substring(1), os);
            // disconnect from ftp server
            ftp.disconnect();
            // assign input stream to read the recently ftp-downloaded file
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        }
    }
    // Send the status line.
    os.writeBytes(statusLine);
    // Send the content type line.
    os.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);
    // Send a blank line to indicate the end of the header lines.
    os.writeBytes(CRLF);

    // Send the entity body.
    if (fileExists) {
        sendBytes(fis, os);
        fis.close();
    } else {
        os.writeBytes(entityBody);
    }

    os.close();
    br.close();
    socket.close();
```

where things get confusing is that in the ftp retrieve part, I don't know if I use the correct method and if I should using "os" the DataOutputStream as argument or something else. Not fully understand the input and output stream thing. what I'm sure is that I want to use

```
    fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```

after I retrieve the file from ftp server. 
So can anyone tell me what should I use in the retrieve part? 
Thanks!